# Organize database (how to store a list)

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

In my database I have table "Announcement" with fields:

```
id int,
text varchar,
sent_date date.
```

Also table "Group" with fields:

```
id int, 
name varchar.
```

Each announcement submitted to any number of groups(from 1 to all). How to store this relation in database?

I'm using MySQL and Hibernate in java web project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a third table (I call it announcement_group) with two columns:

```
announcement_id REFERENCES Announcement(id)
group_id REFERENCES Group (id)
```

Read more about Foreign Keys from the documentation here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

In your query you will want to use a

```
SELECT group_id WHERE announcement_id=<your id here> from announcement_group;
```